# Excel VBA code for long url to hyperlink with display text from separate cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has (among other non-relevant things) a list of book titles in one column and their accompanying URLs from our company bookstore in another. These URLs, with their embedded tracking coding, are often very long, and usually exceed the 255 character limit.  This is a working document - I add to it frequently - so I need a code that will work on only the rows I choose. What I want to do is: select the URLs I'm currently working on and have VBA, in a new cell on the same row, create a Hyperlink that displays the book title for each url.

I have cobbled together a piece of code that works for one cell only. What I'm having trouble with is making this work for a group of cells that I have selected:

'Good for one cell only
Sub insertVeryLongHyperlink()

```
Dim curCell As Range
Dim longHyperlink As String
Dim title As String

Set curCell = Range("R2")
title = [c2]
longHyperlink = [R2]

curCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("t2"), _
                Address:=longHyperlink, _
                SubAddress:="", _
                ScreenTip:=title, _
                TextToDisplay:=title
```

End Sub

Any help would be appreciated. This would be SO much easier if it weren't for the character limit. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a `For Each .. Next` loop structure. Try this (untested):

```
Sub insertVeryLongHyperlinks()
Dim allCells as Range
Dim curCell As Range
Dim longHyperlink As String
Dim title As String

Set allCells = Range("R2:R10") '## Modify as needed

For each curCell in allCells
    title = Cells(currCell.Row, "C").Value
    longHyperlink = curCell.Value

    curCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=curCell.Offset(0,1), _
                Address:=longHyperlink, _
                SubAddress:="", _
                ScreenTip:=title, _
                TextToDisplay:=title
Next

End Sub
```

Documentation on the `For Each ... Next` and other VBA statements is available here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692812%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much, David! This worked beautifully. Just for any others out there that may use this, there are a few typos "currCell" vs. the actual "curCell" that will stop the macro from running. An easy fix, and it works great. Thanks again! And thanks for pointing me in the right direction for the For Each ... Next statements.